# Android: WebView Scroll Animation

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation

i am implementing an app which has some contents to show in webview. 
i am so far achieved smooth animation of scrolling webview contents using the object Animator.

Now what issue i am facing is that it is working fine for first and second page and scrolls as demand. but when i want to scroll on 3rd page what issue i have is that it starts scrolling from first page then moving to second and then to third i dont want this to happen i want is that webview should maintain its scroll position and scroll from the current position.

here is my code so far to make the webview contents scroll using objectanimator.

```
            if (incre <= totalPages) {
                    incre++;
                    totalNumberofPages = totalNumberofPages + incre;
                    // view.loadUrl("javascript:pageScroll("
                    // + incre * view.getWidth() + ")");

                    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view,
                            "scrollX", 0, incre * view.getWidth());
                    anim.setDuration(4000);
                    anim.start();

                    // view.scrollTo(incre*view.getWidth(), 0);

                    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // view.scrollTo(0, incre*view.getWidth());

                            view.scrollTo(incre * view.getWidth(), 0);
                            ReaderActivity.txt_numberofpages_left
                                    .setText("Page:  " + incre + " of "
                                            + totalPages);
                            ReaderActivity.txt_leftPage.setText(""
                                    + totalNumberofPages);
                            ReaderActivity.txt_RightPage.setText(""
                                    + (totalNumberofPages + 1));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening due to this line of code

```
  ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view,
                        "scrollX", 0, incre * view.getWidth());
                anim.setDuration(4000);
                anim.start();
```

after scrollX u are sending hardcoded 0 which will make your contents to scroll from start to the position maintain the last position and pass that position instead of this 0.